# Positioning the fancybox box?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

How do I modify the positioning of the fancybox box? I want it to be positioned so that it floats right within my container div...

Thanks for all your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

line 255 of jquery.fancybox-1.2.6 has this bit of code

```
var itemOpts = {
  'left':       itemLeft,
  'top':        itemTop,
  'width':  width + 'px',
  'height': height + 'px'
};
```

change the 'left' value to move the fancy box left or right

Answer (score 2):

You can affect the positioning of the wraper for fine tuning using those:

```
$("#fancybox-wrap").css("margin-left","-75px");
$("#fancybox-wrap").css("margin-top","60px");
```

but you will have to adjust it to your needs as well as calculating the viewport dimensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try slipping something like this into your jquery:

```
$("#fancy_outer").css({"float":"right","position":"static"});
```